# Does each Japanese copula, だ, な, に, introduce a new clause?

Tags: japanese, clauses, copula

In the book The Japanese Copula: Forms and Functions there's a passage that says:

> The existence of an **adverbial copula** is expected when we consider the fact that adjectives inflect to end form, the pre-norminal form and the adverbial form without the help of the copula *ar-*

Trying to wrap my head around what is an adverbial copula, I realized the following:

In Japanese, you can move a verb to before a noun to create a subordinate adjectival clause.

```
castle SUB to move
城     が  動く
The castle moves.

to move castle
動く     城
A castle that moves. A moving castle.
```

A copula is a verb, so you can do the same with it, except that な is the adjectival version and だ is predicative.

```
country SUB peaceful COP
国      が  平和      だ
The country is peaceful.

peaceful COP country
平和     な   国
The country that is peaceful. A peaceful country.
```

So does this mean that every na-adjective in Japanese technically introduces a new clause? Because な is a copula. A copula is a verb. You can't have two verbs in a single clause. So every time there's a な there must be a new clause, right?

Likewise:

```
     COP-ADV
平和 に       生きる
To live peacefully.
```

If に is an adverbial copula, that means 平和に is a subordinate adverbial clause?

Comment: "A copula is a verb" is a proposition that requires justification in the language-specific case of Japanese. But leaving that aside, there are two competing grammatical analyses of nominal adjectives like *heiwa*. In one, the *-na* has been grammaticalized as an inflection, and *heiwa-na kuni* is parallel to *oki-i kuni* (under this assumption *heiwa-na* is one word). The other analysis is as you propose, and under this assumption, yes, the *no/ni/na* is an inflected copula and *heiwa na-* a syntactic unit equivalent to *heiwa da* (or *ringo da*), only in subordinate position.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on [japanese.se].